# Python equivalent to xdg-mime query filetype

Tags: python, mime-types, xdgutils

I'm looking for a python library that provides that returns exactly the same mime type for a given file as the bash command `xdg-mime query filetype <filename>`. The goal is to use that function to find all file in a diretory with a certain mime type (`application/mbox`)

I'm aware of the `xdg` library, but none of its functions returns the same value as the `xdg-mime` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your own mapping to the python mimetypes module - so You can call xdg-mime on all the extensions you need and then create a file that you feed to mimetypes like this:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.init()
extra={".123": "application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3"}
[mimetypes.add_type(value, key) for key, value in extra.items()]

# testing

mimetypes.guess_type("x.123")
```

gives "application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3"

Comment: `xdg-mime` doesn't rely on the file extensions, so this won't work. In my case the files don't even have an extension.

Comment: There is a python binding to libmagic as well - I guess that is the most straight forward option when bypassing file extension. https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: libmagic only says `ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`